# How to find the most occurrence of a string within a List of string?

Tags: c#, .net

Example input:

```
List<string> input = new List<string>();
input.Add("\nHello \nWorld");
input.Add("My \nname \nis \John");
input.Add("\n\n\n\n Just for fun \n\n");
```

Targeted string: "\n"

Expected output: "**\n\n\n\n Just for fun \n\n** has the most "\n" and the number of occurrence is **6**"

**Notes:**

1. Search string is **case insensitive**, \n and \N should be considered as 2 occurrences.
2. The user will enter the string to look for. \n is just an example. With the example above, if the user enters "m", the expected output would be **My \nname \nis \John** with 2 occurrences

Comment: Have you attempted solving this yourself yet?

Comment: Also this is not clear - for example when you search "bb" in "abbba" the number might be 2 or 1.

Comment: With the edit you forgot to include **Whether you need fries or not**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
var MaxIndex =  input.Select((r, i) => 
                new 
                { 

                  OccuranceCount = r.Count(c =>  char.ToUpperInvariant(c) == char.ToUpperInvariant(searchChar)),                         
                  Index = i 
                })
             .OrderByDescending(t => t.OccuranceCount)
             .FirstOrDefault();
```

So for the following code:

```
List<string> input = new List<string>();
input.Add("\nHello \nWorld");
input.Add("My \nname \nis John");
input.Add("\n\n\n\n Just for fun \n\n");

char searchChar = '\n';

var MaxIndex =  input.Select((r, i) => 
                new 
                { 

                  OccuranceCount = r.Count(c =>  char.ToUpperInvariant(c) == char.ToUpperInvariant(searchChar)),                         
                  Index = i 
                })
             .OrderByDescending(t => t.OccuranceCount)
             .FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine("Line: {0}, Occurance Count: {1}", input[MaxIndex.Index], MaxIndex.OccuranceCount);
```

Comment: @Selman22, "Search string is case insensitive, \n and \N should be considered as 2 occurrences."

Comment: I'm confused, it is supposed to return 6 because input[2] "\n\n\n\n Just for fun \n\n" has a total of 6 \n

Comment: @C.J., I misread the question, check the edited answer, I guess this is what you are looking for.

Comment: The code you gave me can only search for char, what if I need to search a string?

Comment: I tried to modify your code but I don't understand a thing about the LINQ query

Comment: @C.J., that is a different question and out of scope with the current question. Something like `input.Select(r=> r.Split(new[]{searchStr}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length).OrderByDescending(r=> r).FirstOrDefault();` would give you the max count for your search string.